# C# 'get' accessor not recognised

Tags: c#, xna, get, accessor

From http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/tutorial/2dgame/creating_the_player, it is instructed that this code be used:

```
public int Width()
    {
        get { return PlayerTexture.Width; }
    }

    public int Height()
    {
        get { return PlayerTexture.Height; }
    }
```

However, the 'get' accessor doesn't appear to be recognized at all. I get the following errors:

- The name 'get' does not exist in the current context.
- Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

Am I missing a 'using System.(Something)' line? I've seen this used successfully countless times while investigating my problem but I can't find anyone who has run into the same thing.

I am using XNA Game Studio 4.0 with Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express. This is my full code for the Player.cs class:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace Shooter
{
class Player
{
    private Texture2D PlayerTexture;
    public Vector2 Position;
    public bool Active;
    public int Health;

    public int Width()
    {
        get { return PlayerTexture.Width; }
    }

    public int Height()
    {
        get { return PlayerTexture.Height; }
    }

    public void Initialise(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position)
    {
        PlayerTexture = texture;
        Position = position;
        Active = true;
        Health = 100;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(PlayerTexture, Position, null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This isn't a valid property declaration:

```
public int Width()
{
    get { return PlayerTexture.Width; }
}
```

The `()` part is incorrect - that looks like you're trying to declare a method rather than a property. You should have:

```
public int Width
{
    get { return PlayerTexture.Width; }
}
```

(I haven't checked the rest, but that may well be all that's wrong.)

Comment: Jon, I'm in awe of that answering speed!

Comment: Wow, worked perfectly. Thanks a ton, man! Will accept the answer as soon as it allows.

Comment: Yep, faster than I could type mine, LOL